# AxMSTSCLib support for Server 2012r2

Tags: c#, activex, rdp

I have written a custom RDP application using AxMSTSCLib, I am having the hardest time getting it to connect to Server 2012/r2.

I have tried all AxMsRdpClient2 - 7 with no luck, here are the values of my rdp

```
AxMsRdpClient7 rdp = new AxMsRdpClient7();

rdp.AdvancedSettings6.RDPPort = Convert.ToInt16(portBox.Value);
                rdp.UserName = username;
                IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdp.GetOcx();
                secured.ClearTextPassword = password;
                rdp.Connect();
```

Connected value is "2"
        ExtendedDisconnectReason    exDiscReasonNoInfo  MSTSCLib.ExtendedDisconnectReasonCode

The control fails to connect, what am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: RDP does work with the normal rdp client?

Comment: Yes, mstsc opens the connection with no issues.

Comment: It exposes lots of events.  Like OnFatalError, OnLogonError, OnWarning.  If you don't subscribe them then you can't find out what went wrong.

Comment: I think I got it, I had to: rdp.AdvancedSettings8.EnableCredSspSupport = true;

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to set the following value to true

```
rdp.AdvancedSettings8.EnableCredSspSupport = true;
```